# Use datatemplate without listview

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to know if it's possible to use a data template and a list system without the listview controller on xamarin forms.

Comment: You can definitely roll your own controls that use the templating engine. It would just take a whole lot of additional work with custom renderers for each platform etc. If you want to look into that you can check out the source code for Xamarin Forms since it's open source to see how they implemented the ListView.

I think the -2 is because this is quite a broad question that doesn't have an easy answer.

Comment: Okay. Your response is very useful! thank you! I'm going to look that.

Comment: If it helped you, please consider accepting the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely roll your own controls that use the templating engine. It would just take a whole lot of additional work with custom renderers for each platform etc. If you want to look into that you can check out the source code for [Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) since it's open source to see how they implemented the ListView. I think the negative voting is because this is quite a broad question that doesn't have an easy answer.